# Is it possible to write a binary file import extension for vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, binaryfiles

I want to display some informations of a binary file in vs code.
Is it possible to write an extension for vs code, such that when selecting that file in the Explorer (or opening it directly) you see some text extracted from the binary file by that extension?

So the core functionality of that extension would be (simplified) a binary to text converter.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any success with this? Trying to do the same.

Comment: @RayKoopa Not really. I looked into the source code of vs code and it seems that an extension could not solve this problem. But I am not an vs code expert.

Comment: Hmm, that's sad. VS 2017's support is kinda horrible for this too.

Comment: @RayKoopa This post here seems not to reach the vs code team. Maybe we should post this question as an github issue?

Comment: Possible use-case: Debugging a Java application and jumping into a *.class file.

Comment: i think i previously found an issue for it. not sure what the status was.

Answer (score 1):

The VS Code team member has confirmed they do not have support for registering content providers for binary files in [my issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/53121).

> > I've inspected the workspace.onDidOpenTextDocument and window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor APIs, but neither seems to be called when opening binary files.
> >
> > Is there a way to display fallback content using registerTextDocumentContentProvider (or otherwise) for binary files?
>
> That's why these types all carry Text in their names, TextEditor, TextDocument, etc. They can only handle textual, not binary data ;-)

No explanation as to why this works for PDFs, probably special-cased.

Comment: Can it be the PDFs are previewed in an HTML window? I heard it has been "abused" for images before.

Comment: The VS Code PDF extension uses the provider API and it seems to work but only with text files and PDFs, no other binary data types: https://github.com/tomoki1207/vscode-pdfviewer/blob/master/src/pdfProvider.ts#L6

Comment: I see. It does just host it in an iframe in the end as i can see from that.

Comment: Yup, the content provider is for recognizing when a user has clicked on a file in the Explorer tree. You can always use an iframe for any binary format, but not with the open-on-click support without this API.

Comment: Alright. i wished for a conversion step to be possible between opening the binary file, and then displaying it in the text editor :o

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer Thank you for figuring that out! In my opinion PDF are a special case of many other possible special cases. Thus I am not totally happy with the answer on github.

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer Now I used the content provider and added a context menu entry on the explorer tree: https://github.com/lochbrunner/vscode-rosbag

Comment: is this still the answer? For example, if I want to create a VScode extension to open `.docx` files, is that possible? Word files are binary, the extension would open the docx and read all the *text* and then show that in VSCode. Formatting would be gone, but that's fine for my experiment here. Word is a simple example, but my use case is something else: I have a custom binary file and I know how to handle it **as text**, so I wanted to create a VS extension so people could use it as text

Comment: @JobaDiniz Any update on your question? So far I wrote an external app to accept binary files and convert them to text on the fly, opening with the default text editor - very ugly as it has to watch for changes in a temporary directory.