# VSCode API registerTextDocumentContentProvider for binary files

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'd like to offer an option to display fallback content for binary files (of certain extensions) in VS Code.

I've inspected the [`workspace.onDidOpenTextDocument`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#workspace.onDidOpenTextDocument) and [`window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor) APIs, but neither seems to be called when opening binary files.

Is there a way to display fallback content using `registerTextDocumentContentProvider` (or otherwise) for binary files?

I have inspected two extensions which are sort of related for how they do it:

- VS Code PDF extension relies on the fact that for PDFs the API methods are called
- VS Code HexDump extension enforces using a content menu command so the API methods are probably not called

There is a [related issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/566) in the GitHub repository, but it seems to indicate this is not doable, because `TextDocument` cannot be made from binary files.

Comment: I'd also like to know this. I want to convert some binary file to XML upon loading and back to binary when saving it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50481300/is-it-possible-to-write-an-binary-file-import-extension-for-vs-code

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate, but I cannot close this question as duplicate yet now that you've found it as the other one doesn't have an accepted or upvoted answer.

Comment: Yep, that's why I didn't flag, but comment about the duplicate :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to write an binary file import extension for vs code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50481300/is-it-possible-to-write-an-binary-file-import-extension-for-vs-code)

Comment: Also related to [Event that fires when a non-text file has been opened / selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54062785/vscode-event-that-fires-when-a-non-text-file-has-been-opened-selected).